# Trouble with overriding method toString in Java program

Tags: java

I'm writing a program wherein I define the class Function, and have methods to perform arithmetic operations with them.  In the output, in my FractionDemo class, I run into problems trying to write the output, getting the @12f9de etc stuff.  So I know I need to override the `toString` function, but I'm running into a cannot find symbol error.

Here's my code:

Function:

```
public class Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public void setNumerator(int numerator)
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        return;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int denominator)
    {
        this.denominator = denominator;
        return;
    }

    public int getNumerator()
    {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator()
    {
        return denominator;
    }

    public static Fraction add(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        Fraction fraction3 = new Fraction(((fraction1.getNumerator() * fraction2.getDenominator()) + (fraction1.getDenominator() * fraction2.getNumerator())), (fraction1.getDenominator() * fraction2.getDenominator()));
        return fraction3;
    }

    public static Fraction subtract(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        Fraction fraction3 = new Fraction(((fraction1.getNumerator() * fraction2.getDenominator()) - (fraction1.getDenominator() + fraction2.getNumerator())), (fraction1.getDenominator() * fraction2.getDenominator()));
        return fraction3;
    }

    public static Fraction multiply(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        Fraction fraction3 = new Fraction((fraction1.getNumerator() * fraction2.getNumerator()), (fraction1.getDenominator() * fraction2.getDenominator()));
        return fraction3;
    }

    public static Fraction divide(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        if (fraction2.getNumerator() != 0)
        {
            Fraction fraction3 = new Fraction((fraction1.getNumerator() * fraction2.getDenominator()), (fraction1.getDenominator() * fraction2.getNumerator()));
            return fraction3;
        }
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Division by Zero");
    }
}
```

FractionDemo:

```
public class FractionDemo
{      
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fraction fraction1 = new Fraction(4,7);
        Fraction fraction2 = new Fraction(5,6);

        Fraction fractionSum = Fraction.add(fraction1, fraction2);
        System.out.println(fractionSum);

        Fraction fractionDif = Fraction.subtract(fraction1, fraction2);
        System.out.println(fractionDif);

        Fraction fractionProd = Fraction.multiply(fraction1, fraction2);
        System.out.println(fractionProd);

        Fraction fractionDividend = Fraction.divide(fraction1, fraction2);
        System.out.println(fractionDividend);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("The result is:  " + numerator + "/" + denominator);
    }
}
```

Anyway, is there any way I can get the output to be correctly formatted?  It says it can't find my variables in the toString section at the bottom of FractionDemo.  No matter whether I use the variable names, a function call like [fractionSum.getNumerator], or anything.  I'll say right away that I don't really understand the overriding toString thing, I'm pretty new to Java.

Let me know if there's anything I should add.

Answer (score 3):

Your `toString` method needs to be in your `Fraction` class, not in `FractionDemo`.

Comment: +1 - and since it is in the wrong class, it cannot refer to instance variables of the right class.  Hence the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

The `toString` has to be defined in the `Fraction` class, *not* in the `FractionDemo` class.

**UPDATE**: And since you're at it, make the class `final`, make the fields `private final`, remove the setters and make your `toString` return the *raw* fraction representation, without the phrase `"The result is: "` (that should be the job of `FractionDemo`):

```
public final class Fraction 
{

  private final int numerator;
  private final int denominator;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
      return (numerator + "/" + denominator);
  }

  ...
}
```

The rationale is that `Fraction` should be an immutable value class.

Also, I believe you should not accept a denominator of zero:

```
public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    if (denominator == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator can't be zero!");
    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
}
```

And, you should implement `equals` and `hashCode` to make your class have true value semantics.

Comment: That seemed to do it.  It's possible that That was what I did before, when I used it in a lab exercise.  I didn't really understand it at the time, so I honestly don't remember where I defined it.  I guess that does it.  Now all I have to do is wait for my work to be critiqued.  :P

Comment: @user1786288: added some more ideas.

Comment: Agreed with all of the above - in addition you may want to look at this thread for considerations of performance and flexibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925423/is-it-better-practice-to-use-string-format-over-string-concatenation-in-java

Comment: @Romski, the Java compiler translates this kind of string concatenation to `new StringBuilder().append(numerator).append("/").append(denominator).toString()`, which is hard to beat.