# Log4j Implicit String Formatting

Tags: java, logging, log4j, string-formatting

I am using `log4j v1.2.14` for logging in my project and I am also using `Java 7` [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to put variables in my output. Currently I am writing

```
LOGGER.info(String.format("Your var is [%s] and you are [%s]", myVar, myVar1));
```

Is this really the best way to output strings? I feel that `log4j` should have this implemented implicitly as below:

```
LOGGER.info("Your var is [%s] and you are [%s]", myVar, myVar1);
```

Have I missed something? Further, are there any Java logging frameworks that support this?

Comment: Look at slf4j, which I think implements this approach

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)'s api provides "[parameterized logging](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance)", which allows you to do exactly that, although with a slightly different syntax. The example there is:

```
logger.debug("Value {} was inserted between {} and {}.", newVal, below, above);
```

For an implementation, you can use Logback which implements slf4j natively, or the slf4j bindings to connect with log4j or other loggers. [The User Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) explains that, along with a short example.

Comment: Just for additional information (maybe this has changed in the meantime): The plain log4j API supports this as well. The same code as you already wrote can be used.

Answer (score 16):

Using `String.format`, `+`, or a string formatter other than the one provided by your logging system (`log4j` for example) is considered as a bad practice.

Usually, in the code there are lots of low level logs (debug, info) you don't want to see in production. If you use for example `String.format` to format the string to log, then you will allocate on the heap and format a new `String`, which can be very long and consume resources, even if at the end nothing will be logged (for example if the `log4j` min level is set to warning or error).

By using the logger formatter system (like the one from `log4j`), you allow your logger to avoid the generation of the formatted string if it doesn't need to be logged.

This may make a great difference in some cases.

Comment: "is considered as a bad practice" ??

Comment: Please elaborate on why that's bad practice.  Also, a followup question (and I think the OP's actual question), what is the string formatter provided by log4j?  Does one exist?

Comment: This went a bit off-topic with what was asked but it is exactly what I was searching for (why the log4j parameters are better than using String.format). Thanks. Extra resource: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance

Comment: I guess [calling varargs function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) still implicitly allocates an `Array`. In this case, surrounding the log line with `log.isDebugEnabled()` should reduce the overhead even further.

Answer (score 14):

Log4j supports internal formatting.  I haven't found it documented anywhere, but I saw an example of it here:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html

I tried it out and it works!  I'm on log4j 2.11.2.

```
int i = 42;
String str1 = "the answer";
String str2 = "life, the universe, and everything";
console.info("{} is {} to {}", i, str1, str2);
```

Looking at the javadoc for Logger, I'd say it was introduced in Lo4j 2, and supports up to 10 parameters.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html

Answer (score 3):

Btw, In this scenario there is not much difference between using `+` to add your variables to the string and `String.format` - unless you really want to reuse the "Your var is..." in all your logs.

slf4j lets you log as

`log.info("Your var is {} and you are {}", myVar, myVar1);`

Note the use of `{}` instead of print formatters. Also this requires Java >= 1.5

Comment: Besides my personal preference, it is recommended best practice to use `String.format()`, usually because it is easier to read and modify:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925423/is-it-better-practice-to-use-string-format-over-string-concatenation-in-java

Comment: `+` will allocate as many `String`s as there are `+` sings minus 1. `format()` will only allocate one `String` and one `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the "use `logger.debug(format, varargs)`" approach first, because it doesn't allocate extra `String` when it's not needed.

But then it occurred to me that `logger.debug(String format, Object... varargs)` still allocates an `Array` for the varargs.

Tried this on https://godbolt.org/noscript/java

```
class VarargTest {
    static boolean debugging = false;
    static void debug(String format, Object... args) {
       if (debugging) {
           System.out.println(String.format(format, args));
       }
    }

    static void logVarargs(int n) {
        debug("debug message {}", n);
    }

    static void logIf(int n) {
        if (VarargTest.debugging) {
            debug("debug message 2 " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

and indeed, the resulting `debug()` call allocates an `Array`.

So the fastest code should be

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("format {}", arg);
}
```

If it's not super performance critical, a more readable and reasonably fast code would be simply

```
    logger.debug("format {}", arg);
```

Comment: Many loggers (logback, log4j2, etc) implement non variadic versions of the parametric logging functions up to 3 arguments to prevent this array allocation overhead for simple use cases, some implement it up to 9.