# Eclipse - Sonar S2629 possible false positive with new String

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm using latest Eclipse and Sonar plugin

In [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses) for logging there's the following line:

```
log.debug("Request body: {}", new String(body, "UTF-8"));
```

Which should create String only if in DEBUG level:

```
/**
 * Log a message at the DEBUG level according to the specified format
 * and argument.
 * <p/>
 * <p>This form avoids superfluous object creation when the logger
 * is disabled for the DEBUG level. </p>
 *
 * @param format the format string
 * @param arg    the argument
 */
public void debug(String format, Object arg);
```

But Sonar is marking it as `squid:S2629`:

> "Preconditions" and logging arguments should not require evaluation (squid:S2629)

And give examples with concatenation

> logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "Something went wrong: " + message);  // Noncompliant; string concatenation performed even when log level too high to show DEBUG messages

Is it a false positive sonar warning or am I missing something?

This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388341/built-in-string-formatting-vs-string-concatenation-as-logging-parameter) which is generally asking about the rule concept, which is concatenation, but not formatting with creating object as `new String`

Also [link](https://dba-presents.com/index.php/jvm/java/120-use-the-built-in-formatting-to-construct-this-argument) of an answer says creating `new Date()` isn't creating an issue with built in format:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     LOGGER.info("The program started at {}", new Date());
> }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Logging this way, you avoid performance overhead for strings concatenation when nothing should be actually logged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In non-DEBUG mode the line

```
log.debug("Request body: {}", new String(body, "UTF-8"));
```

instead of

```
log.debug(MessageFormatter.format("Request body: {}", new String(body, "UTF-8")));
```

avoids the creation of the string that is created via [`MessageFormatter.format(String messagePattern, Object arg)`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), but not the creation of the other string that is created by **`new String(body, "UTF-8")`**.

This means it is **not a false positive**, because the arguments are calculated first before the logging method is called.

As long as [SLF4J does not support lambda expression to lazy evaluate arguments](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371), the following utility method can be used as a workaround:

```
private static Object lazyToString(final Supplier<String> stringSupplier) {
    return new Object() {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return stringSupplier.get();
        }
    };
}
```

This can be used to limit the converting of the byte array into a string to the DEBUG mode only:

```
log.debug("Request body: {}", lazyToString(() -> new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

Answer (score 3):

While the use of lambda or lazy lambda is fine, there is still the good old `isDebugEnabled` way:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
  log.debug("Request body: {}", new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

That's won't fix the `String` being created (because you want to display it after all), but that would not consume memory when debug mode is disabled.