# Generating Messages approaches

Tags: java, string

At https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/usage.html I found this:

```
// recommended
System.out.printf("Character %c is invalid.%n", codePoint);

// not recommended
System.out.println("Character " + String.valueOf(char) + " is invalid.");
```

Why is one recommend and why the other is not?

**UPDATE**

The arguments provided by the documentation have not much meaning for me excepting the localization one:

> This following approach is simple and avoids concatenation, which
>   makes the text more difficult to localize as not all languages insert
>   numeric values into a string in the same order as English.

Comment: as it says, it's "difficult to localize". (besides the second example wont even compile, because `char` is a type name, and can't be a variable. I'd recommend you look for some better and more up to date learning resource. Just because Oracle bought Java doesn't mean their website is a good place to learn about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("Character %c is invalid.%n", codePoint); //Recommended
```

The above approach is recommended because of localization of string is easier in this way.
With respect to performance, this approach is not recommended as answered by @oleg.cherednik.
This is already answered (more details available here) [Is it better practice to use String.format over string Concatenation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925423/is-it-better-practice-to-use-string-format-over-string-concatenation-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

```
"Character " + String.valueOf(char) + " is invalid."
```

JVM transform this to `StringBuilder`. Bud DO NOT USE + for string IN LOOP. In this case, every when you use +, NEW STRING will be created and put into StringPool.