# When to use String#concat() method in Java?

Tags: java, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I've been through different topics about String concatenation performance. Almost answer recommend using `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` to reduce overhead cost (or `+` operator if concatenation statement outside the loop). It's pretty clear, but I still wonder why Java has String `format()` and `concat()` method although it's ineffective. Performance test here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087703/10393067). Someone mentioned String `format()` may be useful for `Localization` purpose (I don't understand much, howsoever I already have a keyword to search later), but what's the purpose of the remaining one? Does it only useful for compatibility backward?

Comment: Format isn't ineffective... Please quote your sources

Comment: @cricket_007: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925423/is-it-better-practice-to-use-string-format-over-string-concatenation-in-java)

Comment: @logbasex That link doesn't say anything is ineffective.

Comment: [The newer research](http://www.pellegrino.link/2015/08/22/string-concatenation-with-java-8.html): @khelwood

Comment: @logbasex Nor does that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

Comment: @Bentaye: It doesn't. I don't know why we need String `concat()` method while the better one is available.

Comment: @logbasex it states "The concat method should be faster. However, with more strings the StringBuilder method wins, at least in terms of performance." and `+` uses StringBuilder

Comment: @Bentaye The implementation changed in Java 9 (see [JEP 280: Indify String Concatenation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280)) and now appears to use [`java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html).

Comment: @Slaw fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#concat` and `+` exist to provide a minimalistic *set of operations* on the type String.

They are not efficient if used multiple times.

But they have their own right as type operations `"xxx" + "yyy"` you do not want to specify using a StringBuilder. (Furthermore there it is a compile time concatenation.)

`StringBuffer` is a mistake IMHO. It is slower that the newer `StringBuilder` as it is synchronized, but one would rarely add something rom two threads (unordered).

`String::concat` may be a method reference useful for stream reduction or such.